# Is it possible to ssh into Raspberry PI without login?

Tags: raspberry-pi, pi, raspberry-pi4, kali-linux

I am running Kali and was wondering if Is it possible to ssh into Raspberry PI without login? Because when I boot up the PI, it shows the kali login page. Can I still ssh into it without first logging in? I am on RasPI-4b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without logging in by simply doing: `ssh kali@"ip address"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes loggin in via ssh is independent of who is logged in inside of the gui. you can have multiple users logged in at the same time with ssh